# Divide the screen in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, window-manager, virtual-desktop

I have to work on a debugger in one window and the source code and testing in another 2 windows. I have one large monitor. Doing Alt+Tab frequently is beginning ot hurt my fingers. I was looking for some way to be able to

1.divide the screen into two halves (e.g. two desktops)

2.Have a window (or a few of them)assigned to each desktop

3.have the ability to switch between desktops with a non alt combo e.g
    (tAB+1,OR F1 etc).
 4. have the ability to switch between windows in
    each desktop with a non alt combo

After googling, I realized that the virtual desktop software may help ,but then they don't show the desktop into the same screen e.g I would like to see desktop 1 and 2 on the same screen

For (3) and(4), I can use autohotkey but I cannot find a way to customize function keys using autohotkey

Any input appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Just a kindly advice, I love using multi monitor but I dont have one at home, so my alternative solution is create a monitor under `Screen Resolution` and use [Teamviewer](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.teamviewer.com%2F&ei=8FOKVef3Kcbm8AX-6bSoCg&usg=AFQjCNEh8HOvb_isGxy72xLcH9h2svj0UA&sig2=aQyjcqEFQw8bBfDQiYG6Yw) to access the second monitor, you can use ipad or any android tab even laptop is fine.

Comment: Thank. This is a nifty solution :-). How do you switch between multiple monitors using keyboard(I wil search for it but just in case you know)

Comment: I use Alt + Tab but if you can't use Alt what about [Flip3d](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/using-windows-flip-3d) ?

Answer (score 0):

For #3 are you saying that you want to have a shortcut key that will move the active window to the other side of your big monitor?  i.e., if it is on the left, move it to the right, or vice versa?  That is not too difficult to do.

Function keys are easy to assign in AutoHotkey:

```
F1::
;your code goes here
return
```

If you want to toggle through the set of windows on one half of a big monitor (i.e., make an Alt+Tab equivalent that doesn't have a GUI but just cycles through the windows) you could assign a shortcut to get all active windows, split them into groups based on which side they are on and then toggle through them if they're on the side of interest.

Another alternative to using Alt+Tab would be to assign F1 to Alt+Tab and F2 to Shift+Alt+Tab (or something along those lines).

Virtual monitor software like DisplayFusion also lets you split a big monitor into desktops so it's like having two monitors inside of one big physical monitor.  If you have a 4000x1200 resolution for example it would split that into two desktops for you sized at 2000x1200 each.  It also adds a button to the title bar that lets you move the window from one "monitor" to the other (i.e., to the other side of a big physical monitor).  Lots of options as well for how you'd like the windows task bar set up and many other features.